# Why does it scroll to wrong position when keyboard is closing? How I could fix that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

With these two code-lines I want to close the virtual keyboard (mobile phone) first and then it should scroll to specific part on the website.

```
// closes keyboard
$('#input').blur();

// scroll to specific part
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#section').offset().top }, 1000);
```

But there are two things I don't want:

1. When keyboard disappears, then the page shouldn't jump.
2. It jumps not to target section, because `"$('#section').offset().top"` is not the right distance since the page is jumping up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a timeout, You need to fire your code after the keyboard closed.
You need to experiment with the times, check what is the smallest timeout you can use.

I don't think you there is an event you can capture with javascript for when the keyboard is closed.

```
// closes keyboard
$('#input').blur();

// scroll to specific part
setTimeout(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#section').offset().top }, 1000);
}, 1000); // 1000 ms = 1 second, for example.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It works, the page jumps to the right section. But it looks bit weird when the page is always jumping, when the keyboard is closing..
Is there a way to have a nicer view?

Comment: @rakael I'm afraid I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: Okey no problem, i try to explain it better :) So there is an input-field on my page and after the user typed his text in and clicks the button, it should closes the keyboard and the page should scroll to a specific part..
But always right after the keboard is closed the whole page spring a little bit up and after it scrolls to the specific section. Now i wish i could make it without the page going up after the keyboard was closing.
Do you have an idea for that?
Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @rakael, I'm afraid I don't know a way. :( I'm not sure there is even a way.

Comment: No worries, but thank you anyway for your useful help!